# Efficient 2D FFT of fixed length real input data in C/C++

Tags: c++, optimization, opencv, fft, fftw

I'm developing an algorithm that calls several times to a FFT function. I have several time constraints (real-time desired) so I need to minimize the time expended in every FFT call.

I'm working with OpenCV library and I have already implemented my code with two different approaches:

- Using FFTW library. Data/memory management + FFT(8ms) = 14ms (in mean, FFT_MEASURE flag).
- Using OpenCV fft function. Data/memory management + FFT (21ms) = 23ms (in mean).

As my input data is always fixed as a real image of 512x512 pixels, do you think if I implement myself the FFT algorithm based in the mathematical definition of DFT, storing the sine/cosine tables can I achieve better performance or the FFTW library is really very optimized? Any better ideas?

All ideas and suggestions will be really appreciated. By now, I don't consider paralellization or GPU implementation.

Thank you

**Update:**

System: Intel Xeon 5130 2.0GHz CPU in Windows 7, Visual Studio 10.0 and FFTW 3.3.3 (compiled following instructions in the site), OpenCV 2.4.3.

Code example for FFT call with FFTW (input: OpenCV Mat CV_32F (1 channel, float type),  output OpenCV Mat CV_32FC2 (2 channels, float type):

```
float           *im_data;

fftwf_complex    *data_in;
fftwf_complex    *fft;      

fftwf_plan       plan_f;

int             i, j, k;

int height=I.rows;
int width=I.cols;
int N=height*width;


float* outdata = new float[2*N];
im_data = ( float* ) I.data;

data_in = ( fftwf_complex* )fftwf_malloc( sizeof( fftwf_complex ) * N );
fft     = ( fftwf_complex* )fftwf_malloc( sizeof( fftwf_complex ) * N );

plan_f = fftwf_plan_dft_2d( height , width , data_in , fft ,  FFTW_FORWARD ,  FFTW_MEASURE );

for(int i = 0,k=0; i < height; ++i) {
    float* row = I.ptr<float>(i);
    for(int j = 0; j < width; j++) {
        data_in[k][0]=(float)row[j];
        data_in[k][1] =(float)0.0;
        k++;
    }
} 

fftwf_execute( plan_f );

int width2=2*width;
// writing output matrix: RealFFT[0],ImaginaryFFT[0],RealFFT[1],ImaginaryFFT[1],...
for( i = 0, k = 0 ; i < height ; i++ ) {
    for( j = 0 ; j < width2 ; j++ ) {

        outdata[i * width2 + j] = ( float )fft[k][0];
        outdata[i * width2 + j+1] = ( float )fft[k][1];
        j++;
        k++;
    }
}

Mat fft_I(height,width,CV_32FC2,outdata);

fftwf_destroy_plan( plan_f );
fftwf_free( data_in );
fftwf_free( fft );


return fft_I;
```

Comment: I tried to implement fft on my own, using sin\cos tables and other omptimizations. I really think the only way to improve fft speed on your own and make it faster than in such libs as fftw is to perfom it in hardware. They really know what they are doing.

Comment: you may work on the memory management, if the dimension is fixed you may reuse the same chuck of memory without performing the allocation at every iteration (assuming you don't need to store old images)

Comment: Don't count on being able to beat FFTW that easily. While it's certainly possible (and I've done it before because it's what I do) it's not something you should attempt unless you have intimate knowledge of modern hardware as well as experience with high-performance computing.

Comment: What are you doing for the other 6ms in the Data/memory management step?  Can that be improved (fewer data copies, vectorizing operations, etc.)?

Comment: I did my best for optimizing this 6ms in the data/memory management, but I'm not an expert in this field, so it's sure it can be improved. I'll put an example of my code in the question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your FFT time with FFTW seems very high. To get the best of out FFTW with fixed size FFTs you should generate a plan using the `FFTW_PATIENT` flag and then ideally save the generated "wisdom" for subsequent re-use. You can generate wisdom either from your own code or using the [fftw-wisdom](http://www.fftw.org/fftw-wisdom.1.html) tool.

Comment: with FFTW_PATIENT I get in mean 7ms for a Intel Xeon 5130 2.0GHz CPU in Windows 7, Visual Studio 10.0 and FFTW 3.3.3 (compiled following instructions in the site). Do you think it's still high?

Comment: Yes, that seems a little high - but you are doing complex-to-complex not-in-place so that probably explains it.

Comment: If you need better performance try using a real-to-complex transform (and make it in-place if possible).

Comment: you mean to don't use float datatype as input?

Comment: No - use float, but use a real-to-complex FFT (r2c), i.e. purely real input, not complex - currently all your imaginary inputs are 0 so you're wasting around 50% of the FFT computation. In-place means you use the same buffer for input and output, which can also help performance.

Comment: I coded the r2c (out-place) version of my code as you suggested. I'm pleased with the results (FFT in 4ms in mean and 9ms with memory and data management). I'll accept this answer, thank you.

Answer (score 1):

The FFT from the [Intel Math Kernel Library](http://software.intel.com/en-us/intel-mkl) (separate from the Intel compiler) is faster than FFTW most of the time.  I don't know if it will be enough of an improvement in your case to justify the price though.

I will agree with the others that rolling your own FFT is probably not a good use of your time (unless you are wanting to learn how to do it).  The available FFT implementations (FFTW, MKL) have been so finely tuned over many years.  I'm not saying that you can't do better, but it would probably be a lot of work and time for marginal gains.

Comment: I have found exactly the opposite when benchmarking, at least for 2D real-to-complex FFTs with image sizes in the 512x512 up to 2048x2048 range on modern Intel CPUs (Core i7 *et al*) - FFTW beats the Intel libraries quite comfortably, particularly if you take the time to generate the best possible plans.

Comment: Ok, most of my experience is with relatively long (>32K) 1D FFTs where it seems that the MKL FFTs are faster.  I have not tried 2D FFTs so I guess I assumed wrongly that the results would hold for the 2D case.

Answer (score 0):

Believe me fftw is realy very optimized, there is very small chance, that you can do it better.

Which compiler you have used for compiling fftw? Sometimes compiler from Intel gives better perfomance than gcc

Comment: I agree with you about FFTW's performance, and it's true that in general ICC gives better results than gcc for normal code, but for FFTW the butterflies are already highly optimised and in my experience the choice of compiler has little effect.